# How to initialize a UITextView programmatically?

Tags: iphone, delegates, uitextview, frame

How can I initialize a UITextView that is nice and pretty. I have the line:

```
textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 150, 100, 100)];
```

but I'd like to make it look nice and I do not know the functions or the syntax to do so. I'd like it to have word wraping and I'd like the corners to be rounded. Also, how can I make it so that the keyboard goes away if the user presses "Return" on the keyboard. And I'd like to make it say "Done" instead of "Return"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the documentation. This is all in there. Specifically:

- you can't set the border, you can only do that for a UITextField
- you'll need to set your delegate and implement -textViewDidChange: to check for returns
- you can set textView.returnKeyType to UIReturnKeyDone to get the Done button.

You might want to consider using a UITextField, as that object's delegate has a very convenient -textFieldShouldReturn: method, and you can, as I said, set its border.

Answer (score 0):

check out the UItextInputTraits protocol that is linked from the UITextView documentation.
All of these properties can be found there, and others.

EX:

```
textView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyTypeDone;
```

Answer (score 0):

- To make the border look close to a UITextField, you can add the following lines.

  ```
  [textView.layer setBorderColor:[[[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] CGColor]];
  [textView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
  textView.layer.cornerRadius = 3;
  textView.clipsToBounds = YES;
  ```
- To release the keyboard by pressing 'Done'('Return') button, you can override the following protocol (UITextViewDelegate) method.

  ```
  - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
  {
       if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
          [textView resignFirstResponder];
          return NO;
       }
       return YES;
  }
  ```